# Parquet file to CSV conversion

Tags: csv, apache-spark, parquet

I want to convert my Parquet file into CSV .
Is there a way for the same as i am only able to find CSV to Parquet file and not vice versa.

Comment: You use Spark? If please please use the good tags (apache-spark).

Comment: Could you provide a code example of what you would like to have ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419975/how-to-copy-and-convert-parquet-files-to-csv

Comment: @mauriciojost: Added tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("infile.parquet")

df.write.csv("outfile.csv")
```

Both "infile.parquet" and "outfile.csv" should be locations on the hdfs file system.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me when using spark 2.1.0. First run spark shell. Something like:

```
./bin/spark-shell
```

then:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val df = sqlContext.parquetFile("parquet-file.parquet")
df.printSchema()
df.write.format("csv").save("directory")
```

it will create csv files in `directory`

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataFrame df = sqlContext.parquetFile("parquet path");  


    df.javaRDD().saveAsTextFile("outputpath");
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in spark

```
spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.2.0
val df = sqlContext.parquetFile("/hdfs/source.parquet")
df.printSchema()
df.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").save("/hdfs/target_csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way I see to do this is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('myfile.parquet')
df.to_csv('myfile.csv')
```

Answer (score -1):

That'll be simple using Spark and Python:

```
for filename in glob.glob("[location_of_parquet_file]/*.snappy.parquet"):
        print filename
        df = sqlContext.read.parquet(filename)
        df.write.csv("[destination]")
        print "csv generated"
```