# How to copy and convert parquet files to csv

Tags: python, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I have access to a hdfs file system and can see parquet files with

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/foo
```

How can I copy those parquet files to my local system and convert them to csv so I can use them?  The files should be simple text files with a number of fields per row.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try

```py
df = spark.read.parquet("/path/to/infile.parquet")
df.write.csv("/path/to/outfile.csv")
```

Relevant API documentation:

- [pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet)
- [pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv)

Both `/path/to/infile.parquet` and `/path/to/outfile.csv` should be locations on the hdfs filesystem. You can specify `hdfs://...` explicitly or you can omit it as usually it is the default scheme.

You should avoid using `file://...`, because a local file means a different file to every machine in the cluster. Output to HDFS instead then transfer the results to your local disk using the command line:

```
hdfs dfs -get /path/to/outfile.csv /path/to/localfile.csv
```

Or display it directly from HDFS:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /path/to/outfile.csv
```

Comment: Can infile.parquet by a location n the hdfs filesystem?

Comment: Yes, *infile.parquet* should be a location on the hdfs filesystem, and *outfile.csv* also. You can specify a path without a scheme as the default is usually hdfs or you can specify `hdfs://...` explicitly.

You should avoid using `file://...` because a local file means a different file to every machine in the cluster. Output to hdfs instead then transfer the results to your local disk using the command line if you really have to.

Answer (score 3):

If there is a table defined over those parquet files in Hive (or if you define such a table yourself), you can run a Hive query on that and save the results into a CSV file. Try something along the lines of:

```
insert overwrite local directory dirname
  row format delimited fields terminated by ','
  select * from tablename;
```

Substitute *`dirname`* and *`tablename`* with actual values. Be aware that any existing content in the specified directory gets deleted. See [Writing data into the filesystem from queries](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-Writingdataintothefilesystemfromqueries) for details.

Comment: Thank you. I have never used hive. I can run hadoop from the command line and there is spark installed too.

Answer (score 3):

Snippet for a more dynamic form, since you might not exactly know what's the name of your parquet file, will be:

```
for filename in glob.glob("[location_of_parquet_file]/*.snappy.parquet"):
        print filename
        df = sqlContext.read.parquet(filename)
        df.write.csv("[destination]")
        print "csv generated"
```